# Really static pages with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, static-pages

Some page in the application must be accessible even application is down. For example pages for 50x errors. The easiest way to do so - create static HTML pages, which will be served by web-server (like apache on Nginx). Most of this pages have a common layout with the application. So, if we change some part of layout in the application we must change all static pages by hand.

What is the best way to store rails pages as static files and recreate it (automatically or by rake task)  on same changes in the project? Is any gem for rails or static-site generator that's able to reuse rails layout and resources (CSS, js, images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There simple rake task (via GIST) to load all files from VIEW_PATH, wrap it with application layout and store it under same path in public. Work with Rails 4.

https://gist.github.com/potapuff/090b2da4a4156c1272430241cb70edc0

```
namespace :static do
  desc 'Render all resources'
  task :publicate => :environment do
    resources(VIEW_PATH).each do |src, dest|
      html= controller.render_to_string(file:src, layout:'application')
      dirname = File.dirname(dest)
      unless File.directory?(dirname)
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(dirname)
      end
      File.write(dest, html)
    end
  end

  def resources search_path
      ... 
  end

  def controller
    ApplicationController.new.tap do |controller|
       ...
    end
  end
end
```

Other possibility is using gem render_anywhere .

In Rails 5 we have new ability to use render outside controllers 
https://medium.com/evil-martians/the-rails-5-post-9c76dbac8fc#1b36

Answer (score 2):

Generally static content goes in your `public` folder which you can configure Nginx or equivalent to route to accordingly without even needing to hit Rails.

For static site generation in Ruby you might want to check out Jekyll https://jekyllrb.com/. You could manage your Jekyll site separately from your Rails site and generate the static HTML/CSS/JS on deployment. There's a `jekyll  watch` command that will listen for file edits and compile your static content accordingly.

Comment: Can I reuse rails layout in jekyll? If no - I will need to have 2 separate layouts and made modification in 2 separated places.

Comment: Not easily, that I'm aware of. Ultimately your layout renders to HTML so you can copy the processed HTML of your layout into Jekyll. Not ideal, but it'll work. There may be a library/gem/tool that does it though. Not sure.

Comment: I have read issue https://github.com/zbruhnke/bloggy/issues/2 for Bloggy (based on Jekyll) about reusing Rails layout. All solution like a Frainkinshtain and need many external gems like Hight Voltage.